# Прокрутить выборку в цикле laravel

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, laravel

Поскажите, пожалуйста

```
$cartProductID = $cartProductID->unique();

  foreach ($cartProductID as $key) {
    $key = $cartProductIDdata = DB::table('products')->where('product_id', $key)->get(); 
  }
```

В `$cartProductID` cодержится массив нужных id, 
количество и значения динамические.
Хочу дальше на основании каждого id сделать выборку из другой таблицы.
Цикл в итоге перезаписывает один массив `$key`. Как сделать, чтоб происходила поочередная выборка с каждым из содержащих в переменной значений id?

Comment: а почему не хотите использовать `whereIn('product_id', $ids_array)`?

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!! Действительно, так работает как нужно

Answer (score 0):

использовать `whereIn('product_id', $ids_array)`